# Export to Excel working in Local but not when deploy thru IIS

Tags: mysql, asp.net, excel, visual-studio-2010, iis

Hi i have a web_application in ASP.Net deployed in IIS, my database is MySQL, my Export_button is working on Local but not when its deployed? below is my code behind Export_button, can you tell me what am i missing?

```
   protected void Export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            excel.Visible = true;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
            int StartCol = 1;
            int StartRow = 1;
            int j = 0, i = 0;

            //Write Headers

            for (j = 0; j < GridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet1.Cells[StartRow, StartCol + j];
                myRange.Value2 = GridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText;
            }

            StartRow++;

            //Write datagridview content
            for (i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < GridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet1.Cells[StartRow + i, StartCol + j];
                        myRange.Value2 = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text == null ? "" : GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch 
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),
        "alertMessage",
        "alert('Unable to export, contact Administrator');", true);

        }
    }
```

UPDATE:
I edited the identity of Microsoft Excel in DCOMCNFG to Interactive User, and when user click the Export_Button, the Exportfile shows but in the Host Server, is it possible to make it shows into the User who click the Export_button?

Comment: which type of error occurred while calling deployed application.

Comment: this application is actually based on MessageBox.Show which is used only in windows form application not in web.

Comment: yes your right, but i did not used MessageBox.Show?

Comment: all right you may give administrator rights to application pool for access Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library.

Comment: How is that? sorry i'm new in ASP.Net

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116955/discussion-between-sanjay-radadiya-and-seryu).

Comment: @sanjayradadiya i already give administrator for application pool, and build and update my deployment folder still nothing happens when Export_button click